# `npm link --save` does not update dependencies on my package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using `npm link package --save` to create a local link to a globally installed package.

It correctly creates the link to the package (and would install it globally in case it were not already installed); but it fails to update the dependencies in `package.json`.

What I am missing here?

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but I usually use `npm install --save package`.

Answer (score 8):

According the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link), `npm link` is not intended to change your `package.json`. It creates symbolic links on your file system for a package.

This allows you to still reference a module by name, but have it pull from your local filesystem:

```
cd ~/projects/node-redis    # go into the package directory
npm link                    # creates global link
cd ~/projects/node-bloggy   # go into some other package directory.
npm link redis              # link-install the package
```

---

If you actually intend to insert a file path in your `package.json`, use `npm install` instead:

```
npm install --save /path/to/package
```

Then you'll see a reference in `package.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
  "local-package": "file:/path/to/package"
}
```

Though I highly recommend you use `npm link` instead, as it makes your `package.json` more portable. If you commit your changes with local file paths, it may become invalid on another system, or if you move around the files.

Comment: my intended use is to have links instead of actual installs in my local node_modules, but apart of it, I would like to have the rest of the install functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You question appeared to be asking _why_ `npm link` does not update your `package.json`. If that's not what you meant to ask, maybe you could rephrase/clarify your question?

Comment: i have edited my question to clarify it. I want to know how to get my package.json dependencies updated when linking locally to a global package.

Comment: I don't want to install it locally, as it is already installed globally, I just want to create a local link to the global install.

Comment: Why does the `npm link` doc says the opposite though? https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link#save
"Save installed packages to a package.json file as dependencies."

Comment: @neeh: If you're not used to something like npm, it's hard to visualize how it all comes together. The language here is oddly crystal clear, but I can recall when I would have been confused by this too. It's two different save types at play here.
What it's saying is true -- It saves the dependency **to the package.json file**. In other words, in the text file called package.json, it adds a line to the dependencies section of that file; something like this: `"axios": "^1.3.4",`.  By default, the value of save=true anyway.
The other save type is saving the actual files of the package.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: Use **[npm-link-better](https://github.com/laggingreflex/npm-link-better)**

---

I created a little tool for this: [npm-link-save](https://github.com/laggingreflex/npm-link-save)

> ## [npm-link-save](https://github.com/laggingreflex/npm-link-save)
>
> `npm-link` with `--save` (or `--saveDev`) to save the linked dependency in your `package.json`.
>
> You can also link **multiple** dependencies with this.
>
> ### Install
>
> ```
> npm i -g npm-link-save
> ```
>
> ### Usage
>
> ```
> npm-link-save express
> # or
> npm-links express
> npm-links -D express // links in devDependencies
> npm-links express morgan // multiple links
> ```

Comment: catch 22... i can't npm install anything before I `--save` a bunch of dependencies, otherwise it's going to blow them all away!

Comment: @Michael Thanks, I noticed it too. I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/laggingreflex/npm-link-better/issues/10) and will try to fix it soon (PRs welcome!).

Answer (score 2):

You're not missing anything, it's just not possible (yet).

There's an open feature request on the npm issue tracker (https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1166).